# How to use require to execute an IIFE that takes arguments

Tags: javascript, requirejs, iife

I know that when you do `require('./file')` where the `file.js` export is an IIFE, that function will immediately run (obviously). I'm just not sure how to deal with this if the IIFE takes arguments.

I'm new to JS go easy on me please.

For something like this:

```
//iifeFile.js

module.exports =
   (function(arg1, arg2){
      //stuff
   })();
```

I feel like I read somewhere that you could run it this way

```
//index.js

const a = require('./iifeFile')(arg1, arg2);
```

but that throws `TypeError: require(...) is not a function`

What is the correct syntax to call this?

Answer (score 0):

Make the `export` a regular function:

```js
module.exports = function(arg1, arg2) {
    // ...
    // return something
};
```

Comment: So is there no way to do this with an iife? I want a line that basically says 'run this whole file and take these arguments'.

Comment: @Oli Why must it be an IIFE? `const a = require('./iifeFile')(arg1, arg2);` now works with this setup.

Comment: I'm using the blessed library and I've tried exporting with both classes and functions and things are pretty inconsistent. Using iifes works very consistently so it would be great to stick with it. I just need to pass an emitter.

This is very helpful though, thanks. I didn't realize that that syntax was actually usable.

Comment: @Oli If you really want to, you could make the IIFE return a function that accepts the two arguments (but I don't really see what benefit that brings).

Comment: Thank you for the help! I didn't realize that doing require when a function is exported like that would immediately run it. Not sure what the purpose of iifes are if this is a thing.